# Don't allow to edit FB sharekit message

Tags: iphone, facebook, sharekit

I am working on a game in iphone using cocos2d. I basically allow the player to share his score and level number after each level on his facebook page and for that i am using Sharekit. I currently share level score, level name and itunes link to the iphone app by creating a SHKItem with text method and then passing this shkitem to SHKFacebook share method but the problem is right now on post to wall facebook page all this information is showed as editable text. I don't want to allow the user to change level score, level name or itunes link. I only want to allow user to append comment to level score, name and itunes link.

I have already looked at sharekit documentation but could not find any method to do this using sharekit. I looked at some facebook games and when they share score for the player they show a editable comment message at the top and the score is not editable. Can i do this using sharekit or any other facebook api for iphone?

Comment: A Facebook user is allows to edit his own wall.  He may want to take back what he said/posted.

Comment: Never mind i found the solution i wanted the Sharekit sharing url method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution i wanted sharekit sharing with url method where i can share a url, some predefined text and user can add his own title for

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can write it all yourself however the Facebook API guidelines do not let you pre-populate any field at all so they will ban your API access for this.

They have started clamping down on this and blocking app access.